# Excluir constraint após pegar o nome da mesma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou rodando a seguinte `query` para obter o nome de 2 `constraints`:

```
select TC.Constraint_Name from information_schema.table_constraints TC
inner join information_schema.constraint_column_usage CC on TC.Constraint_Name = CC.Constraint_Name
where TC.constraint_type = 'Unique' and CC.TABLE_NAME = 'NAVIO'
order by TC.Constraint_Name
```

Como eu posso fazer uma função para excluir cada valor que retornar nesse select ?

Comment: você quer deletar o retorno, é isso? seria o caso só fazer um delete ao invés do select?

Comment: Isso, quero deletar. O problema é que como não sei o retorno preciso do select. No Caso aí é uma constraint. Pra ficar mais claro, sempre vou ter 1 resultado no retorno aí preciso apagar a constraint cujo nome é o retorno da query.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Segue uma alternativa para o teu caso.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + CC.TABLE_NAME + '  DROP [CONSTRAINT] '+ TC.Constraint_Name+' ; GO' 
  from information_schema.table_constraints TC
 inner join information_schema.constraint_column_usage CC on TC.Constraint_Name = CC.Constraint_Name
 where TC.constraint_type = 'Unique' and CC.TABLE_NAME = 'NAVIO'
 order by TC.Constraint_Name
```

Veja se te auxilia, qualquer coisa é só retornar.
Com o retorno você terá o "DROP" das contraints